# Colored hypercubes isomorphism

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, graph-isomorphism

I would like to extend the method to verify isomorphism between cubes with colored faces in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4554420/573047) to $4$-cubes (tesseracts) with colored faces ($2$-faces), allowing rotations and reflections, and if possible, extend it even further to $n$-cubes with colored $2$-faces.

However I am unsure if in the case of the tesseract, taking all the couples of colors of the opposite faces for all the $8$ composing cells ($8$ cubes) is sufficient to identify uniquely the tesseract. Maybe we need also to consider "opposite" cubes in the tesseract, but I am unable to figure it out. Any hint?

Comment: The strategy for cubes is not going to generalize. You just don't have the freedom to swap two opposite $2$-faces in a hypercube by a reflection that leaves the other $2$-faces unchanged, nor permute the opposite pairs however you like. The hypercube has less freedom to move, in some sense, so the isomorphism test is going to be more complicated.

Comment: Intuitively, faces of a cube can have only two relationships: they can be adjacent or opposite. But $2$-faces of a $4$-cube behave more analogously to *edges* of a cube, which can have many relationships: they can share an endpoint, or they can be opposite edges of the same face, or parallel edges sharing no face, or skew edges whose four endpoints are not coplanar. When thinking about the isomorphism of edge-colored cubes, all these relationships would have to be preserved, and it is just as complicated for $2$-face-colored $4$-cubes.